# How to find all the pairs $(i,j)$ such that $i=j\mod 3$ for $i,j=1,2,...,8$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

These are the pairs I found $(4,1),(7,1),(5,2),(8,2),(6,3),(7,4)$

Are there any other?

Also, should pairs like $(1,4), (4,4)$ be included?

Comment: Yes, (1,4) and (4,4) are included because they satisfy $3|i-j$ , which is an equivalent formulation to $i\equiv j\mod 3$

Comment: You forgot $(8,5)$

Comment: @Peter, So the correct answer is $(4,1),(7,1),(5,2),(8,5),(8,2),(6,3),(7,4),(1,4),(1,7),(2,5),(5,8),(2,8),(3,6),(4,7),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8)$

Comment: Yes, those are the pairs.